# `block in set_restricted': method column0= doesn't exist (Sequel::Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, sequel

I have this code:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sequel'
require 'sequel-rails'
require_relative 'support/benchmark_rails'
DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite::memory:')
COUNT=25 
Sequel.extension :migration
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table(:users) do
      primary_key :id
      COUNT.times do |i|
       column :"column#{i}", "varchar(255)"
     end
    end
  end
end

class User < Sequel::Model; end

attributes = {}

COUNT.times do |i|
  attributes[:"column#{i}"] = "Some string #{i}"
end

Benchmark.rails("sequel/#{db_adapter}_create_string_columns", time: 5) do
  User.create(attributes)
end
```

But when I try to run this, it gives the following error:

```
/home/aaditya/Downloads/ruby-bench-suite/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-3.40.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1759:in `block in set_restricted': method name= doesn't exist (Sequel::Error)
    from /home/aaditya/Downloads/ruby-bench-suite/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-3.40.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1746:in `each'
    from /home/aaditya/Downloads/ruby-bench-suite/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-3.40.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1746:in `set_restricted'
    from /home/aaditya/Downloads/ruby-bench-suite/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-3.40.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1257:in `set'
    from /home/aaditya/Downloads/ruby-bench-suite/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-3.40.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1715:in `initialize_set'
    from /home/aaditya/Downloads/ruby-bench-suite/rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sequel-3.40.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:899:in `initialize'
    from benchmarks/bm_sequel_create_string_columns.rb:34:in `new'
    from benchmarks/bm_sequel_create_string_columns.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

I tried to simplify this and tried to run only `User.create(:name=>'Bob')` but with no successful results. What mistake am I making?

There are no problems with the other methods as the same code is running for Active Record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just defining the migration, you aren't actually running the `CREATE TABLE` on the database.  Remove the migration code and just call `DB.create_table`.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating user with name attribute but you don't have name column in your users table created.

Comment: I just tested with that. I have edited the question. I still receive this error.

Comment: Can you try adding attr_accessor :name at the begging of your User class?

Comment: That's strange. I added attr_accessor :column0 in the user class and used only `User.create(:column0=>"Some string 0")`. This gave me this error : ` 'initialize': SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users (Sequel::DatabaseError)
`